# Python "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" for a text file. But opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, capture, sys

I needed to a library specific output and, so I tired it like this way. But I got "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." Error.

Here the code example that I tried...

```
import sys

def print_test():
    print("Printing testing print...!")
    print("line 01")
    print("line 02")
    print("line 03")


print("Before capture")

def main():
    sys.stdout= open("test.txt", 'w')
    print_test()
    sys.stdout.close()
main()

print("After capture")

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines= f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        print(i)

        if "line 01" in lines:
            print("Found line 01")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```py
sys.stdout.close()
```

Effectively you are closing the `stdout` stream for all following `print` calls in your program, if you omit to pass a file object to the `file` parameter.
See definition of `print`'s `file` keyword argument:

> The file argument must be an object with a write(string) method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used.

After `main` is finished all following `print` calls try accessing the re-assigned `sys.stdout` which now is closed. Thus giving you a `ValueError`.

Create a local copy of `sys.stdout` that you can re-assign after your call to `print_test` to circumvent this:

```py
def main():
    stdout = sys.stdout  # create local copy of stdout
    sys.stdout = open("test.txt", 'w')  # change stdout
    print_test()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = stdout  # reassign standard output stream to sys.stdout
```

The other way would be to pass the file object directly to `print` using the `file` keyword

```py
myoutput = open("test.txt", "w")
print("Print to file", file=myoutput)

# pass file object to function
def my_print(file):
    print("function call to print", file=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know this, but after doing `sys.stdout.close()` it seems you cannot open other files.

However there is a better way to print in a file using print anyway, as the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) accept a `file` parameter. You can then do something like :

```
def print_test(f):
    print("Printing testing print...!", file=f)
    print("line 01", file=f)
    print("line 02", file=f)
    print("line 03", file=f)


print("Before capture")

def main():
    f = open("test.txt", 'w')
    print_test(f)
    f.close()
main()
```